# How to split and replace a string?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string

```
$str = 'abcde-da__123123213.xef';
$str2 = 'asdfasd__2342352353.gff';
$str3 = 'twethe__3242323423.pig';
```

I want to replace anything following __ (2 underscores) and before the . (dot) with a new string (number). For example, the above `$str` changes to 'abcde-da__23235239.xef'.

One of the ways is to

```
$temp = explode('.', $str); 
$temp2 = explode('__', $temp[0]);
```

and

```
$new_str = $temp2[0].'__'.time().'.'.$temp[1];
```

But I was thinking if I could use preg_replace instead but I aint very good at regexs

i tried    preg_replace('/__(.*)/', time(), 'abcde-da__123123213.xef');

can you please help writing this regex, or any other simpler way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/(?<=__)([^.]+)(?=\.)/e','dosomething($1)',$str)

(?<=__) - LookBehind expression to match __
([^.]+) - Actual Match Part - match any characters except dot .
(?=\.)  - LookAhead expression to match .
```

`e` in `/e` allows to use php codes in replace part, dosomething() could be any functions like, `time()`,`strtoupper()`,`$1` would be match string between `__` and `.`

For more information about regexes, please take a look at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: How about an explanation of what that does. The guy doesn't understand regex, so that would be helpful for him.

Comment: Excellent .. it works and I can get the required string .. but the regex part just goes over head  :D ..

Answer (score 1):

This regex is simpler:
`/.*?__(.*?)\..*/`

"`.*`" = absolutely anything.  The '?' that follows means to not be greedy, which results in `.*?` matching everything up to __

"`__`" doesn't have any significance in regex, so it's matched literally

"`(.*?)`" again means match everything but don't be greedy.  This will match the numbers

"`\.`" we want to match the period character, but since it's a significant character in regex, we need to escape it so the regex engine knows we mean the actual character and not "anything"

"`.*`" match anything.  We can be greedy here because we're past the part we care about

So...

"`.*?__`" matches everything before the number, and
"`\..*`" matches everything after